# How can I displace a movieclip across the stage when I press a button?

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, keyboard-events

I am, once again, working on a project for a class I'm in and having some trouble figuring out how to get my stick man (movieclip) to move left or right based on when I pressed the button. Currently what I have makes the stick man play a "walking" animation when the arrow keys are pressed, but I want him to also move as well! Here's what I have.

I am suggested to use a timer event to trigger when the buttons are pressed, and using that function to displace him but I'm having some trouble coding that.

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

stop();

var isReady:Boolean=new Boolean();

isReady = true;

var timerWalkLeft:Timer = new Timer(100);

function walkLeft(e:TimerEvent)
{
stickMan.x ++;
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyIsDown);

function keyIsDown(event:KeyboardEvent)
{

if (isReady==false)
{
    return;
}
else
{
    var key:uint = event.keyCode;
    switch (key)
    {
        case Keyboard.LEFT :
            stickMan.gotoAndStop("left");
            walkLeft();
            break;
        case Keyboard.RIGHT :
            stickMan.gotoAndStop("right");
            break;
        case Keyboard.UP :
            stickMan.gotoAndStop("jump")
            break;
        case Keyboard.DOWN :
            stickMan.gotoAndStop("crouch");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my way :

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

stop();
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyIsDown);
var isReady:Boolean = true;// learn shortcuts like that, I don't know your useless teacher but "= new Boolean();" is the same thing as "= false;" or even simpler ";" (false being the default value for boolean type)

var timerWalk:Timer = new Timer(100);
timerWalk.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, movementLoop);
timerWalk.start();

function movementLoop(e:TimerEvent = null)
{
    var mc:* = stickMan;
    if(dir == "left")
       mc.x--;
    else if(dir == "right")
       mc.x++;
}


function keyIsDown(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if(!isReady)// literally "if not isReady"
       return;

    var key:uint = event.keyCode;
    switch (key)
    {
        case Keyboard.LEFT :
            stickMan.gotoAndStop("left");
            dir = "left";
            break;
        case Keyboard.RIGHT :
            stickMan.gotoAndStop("right");
            dir = "right";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked a lot better than what I had but it wouldn't stop displacing after the animation stopped. Any ideas?

Comment: A way to do it: you can label all your stickman animations (from the timeline), and then you change "if(dir == "left")" into "if(dir == "left" && mc.currentlabel == "runningleft")

Answer (score 0):

Use some animation library instead of dealing with timer, it's more easier, look here:
http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/